# Change psd plot to display frequency in Hz instead of kHz

Tags: matlab, units-of-measurement, spectral-density

In MATLAB I can't seem to figure out how to get the dspdata.psd function to display my power spectral density plot in Hz instead of kHz for the x-axis. If anyone knows a solution it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the `dspdata.psd` function, but you can directly change it on the figure after you plot it by:

```
ax = gca();

for i=1:numel(ax.Children)
   ax.Children(i).XData = ax.Children(i).XData*1000;
end
ax.XLabel.String = 'Frequency [Hz]';
```

Note, that I'm using Matlab 2014b - if you are using an older version, you might not have access to ax.Children the same way in that case you can do it like this:

ax = gca();

```
data = get(ax,'Children');
for i=1:numel(data)
   set(data(i),'XData', get(data(i),'XData')*1000);
end
set(get(ax,'XLabel'),'String','Frequency [Hz]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the axis scale from the figure properties(Show Plot Tools and Dock Figure) option. In the X Axis tab, you can modify the X Limits to Hz from KHz.